# Convergence of iteration sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, derivatives, convergence-divergence, numerical-methods, fixed-point-theorems

Let $x_{r+1} = g(x_r) = \alpha x_r + \beta x_r^2$, $r=0,1,\ldots$. Find coefficients $\alpha$ and $\beta$ such that the iterative sequence $(x_r)_{r \in \mathbb{N_0}}$ converges to a fixed real number $a > 0$ with quadratic convergence.

To have quadratic convergence: $g(a) = a, g'(a)=0,g''(a)\neq0$. The first two equations give:
$$\alpha a + \beta a^2=a \Rightarrow \alpha + \beta a=1 \Rightarrow \beta = \frac{1-\alpha}{a}$$ and $$a + 2\beta a = 0 \Rightarrow \alpha = -2\beta a \Rightarrow \alpha = -2\frac{1-\alpha}{a}a \Rightarrow \alpha = 2.$$

So I found $\alpha$ and $\beta$ depends on $a$ and $\alpha$. Is it okay?

Comment: Now insert $α=2$ into the formula for $β$.

Comment: @LutzL so $\beta = \frac{-1}{a}$ is correct? I was skeptical since it still depends on $a$.

Comment: Yes, you get the Newton method for $f(x)=\frac1x-\frac1a$.

Answer (score 1):

Newton's method converges quadratically to simple roots, the root $x=a$ of $f(x)=\frac1a-\frac1x$ is simple, and its Newton method is
$$
x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{\frac1a-\frac1{x_n}}{\frac1{x_n^2}}=2x_n-\frac{x_n^2}a
$$